# Javascript detect when popunder and popup fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I have a site and have put ads that fired popunder(or popup) when users click on links or other elements.So popunders are not in my controll.But i want to know when a popunder if fired to serve another ads to my client(user).
Is there a way(javascript code or jquery) to detect when my site fired a popunder(or popup)?

Comment: got any codes to show?

Comment: Please take a look at the first answer's comment and you will find the answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use `postMessage` in popup/popunder window, to send `acknowledge` message or to send `keeep alive` message in loop ( eg. every time interval ). Then you know that window was opened or is still open.

here is example
https://simpl.info/postmessage/popup/index.html

Comment: Javascript script code that fired popunder are not mine.I am an publisher to propellerads.com.I just have put their codes to my pages.How to detect if their codes had fired popunder to a client(user).This is the real situation.